# How to count how many days since the user was active on the platform in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I want to know how many days passed since the person did her first trip.

I'm triyng this:

```
DATEDIFF(day, first_completed_trip_timestamp, CURRENT_DATE) AS days_since_ft
```

and I get this error:

> QueryValidation: user_error: Attempt 1: presto: query failed (200 OK): "USER_ERROR: com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.SemanticException: line 11:16: Column 'day' cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return this as an interval just by subtracting the values:

```
(CURRENT_DATE - first_completed_trip_timestamp) as days_since_ft
```

If you specifically want the number of days, then use `day()` on the interval:

```
day(CURRENT_DATE - first_completed_trip_timestamp) as days_since_ft
```